# Match and Remove Text Field on Similar Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not a SQL genius by any means, but I also cannot seem to find an answer that addresses this problem. I am pulling text field from Oracle DB - there are 2 types of a fields: `PROBLEM` and `DESCRIPTION`. Quite a bit of the time, the text fields for these 2 types contain exact same text. A sample SQL query (shortening for brevity and clarity) and sample output table are as follows:

```sql
SELECT TICKET, TEXT, TYPE

FROM TABLE

WHERE (TYPE = 'DESCRIPTION' 
        OR TYPE= 'PROBLEM')        
        AND
        (REPORTDATE > TO_DATE('01/01/2015 0:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Sample output Table:

```
TICKET    TEXT    TYPE
123       CLOB    PROBLEM
123       CLOB    DESCRIPTION
111       BLOB    PROBLEM
```

In my case, if you clicked on the CLOB object for either TICKET 123 entry, the text field would have the same contents. i.e. "hello" and "hello". Just threw ticket 111 in there to make table seem more complete.

I have tried a couple different 'IF' statements with no success, and I attribute that to my lack of SQL knowledge. However, in pseudo code, I want to say:

```
IF TICKET PROBLEM TEXT == TICKET DESCRIPTION TEXT:
    FILTER OUT PROBLEM ROW 
    USE DESCRIPTION ROW
```

I do not want to delete - just not pull the PROBLEM row. I know this is a simple if-type statement, I just do not understand how to match actual field contents to one another. How can I match the actual text fields for each row? Specifically, I need to use `DBMS_LOB COMPARE()`. How can I create the dummy filter tables?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete problems where exists a description for the same ticket with the same text. Use `EXISTS` for this. Then, in order to compare CLOBs, you must use `DBMS_LOB.COMPARE`, if I am not mistaken.

```
delete from mytable p
where type = 'PROBLEM'
and exists
(
  select null
  from mytable d
  where d.type = 'DESCRIPTION'
  and d.ticket = p.ticket
  and dbms_lob.compare(d.text, p.text) = 0 -- i.e. d.text = p.text
);
```

Comment: What if I don't want to delete? Just filter - I edited post

Comment: If you want select instead of delete, replace `delete` with `select *`. If you want to select all other rows then negate the where clause: `where not (type = 'PROBLEM' and exists (...))`.

Comment: How are you creating the ```mytable``` variable? Sorry, I do not know much SQL. Here is another questions with the full query before I found the LOB COMPARE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451809/comparing-2-text-fields-sql-error-ora-22835-buffer-too-small-for-clob-to-cha?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is defined thus:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ticket_id int, ticket_type varchar(50), ticket_text varchar(100))
```

then the DELETE statement below would remove the row for ticket "123, CLOB, PROBLEM" in your example data.

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE  ticket_type = 'PROBLEM'
       AND ticket_id IN (SELECT a.ticket_id
                         FROM   mytable a
                                JOIN mytable b
                                  ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
                                     AND a.ticket_text = b.ticket_text
                                     AND a.ticket_type = 'PROBLEM'
                                     AND b.ticket_type = 'DESCRIPTION')
```

You haven't made it clear if **both** the ticket id **and** the text have to match, but your example data implies this is the case.