# Comparing 2 text fields SQL - Error- ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have seen quite of this same error with different solutions on the web, but none seem to solve what I am trying to do. I want to compare 2 text fields: PROBLEMCODE and DESCRIPTION. The text is contained in CLOB and BLOB objects some of which are ~24000 bytes (CHARs?) which throws the error:

```
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4029, maximum: 4000)
```

I fully understand the root cause of this error, but I do not understand how to work around it comparing text fields. I want to check if the text PROBLEMCODE and DESCRIPTION are the same. If they are the same, use the DESCRIPTION row. Sample query and sample output:

```
SELECT TICKET, TEXT, TYPE

FROM TABLE

WHERE (TYPE = 'DESCRIPTION' 
        OR TYPE= 'PROBLEM')
```

Output:

```
TICKET    TEXT    TYPE
123       CLOB    PROBLEM
123       CLOB    DESCRIPTION
111       BLOB    PROBLEM
```

Now, I want to say something like the following, which I think I have accomplished in the full query below, but I am not sure because I cannot test because I keep getting the buffer error.

```
IF TICKET PROBLEM TEXT == TICKET DESCRIPTION TEXT:
    FILTER OUT PROBLEM ROW 
    USE DESCRIPTION ROW
```

So, below is my full query and filtering by single tickets, I am *pretty sure*, but not 100% it filters properly. My question is: How can I adjust to compensate for the buffer error? How can you compare and filter large text fields in SQL/TOAD/Oracle?

LDOWNERCOL = TYPE

```
SELECT 
       *   
FROM (SELECT 
        TICKETID, LDTEXT, LDOWNERCOL
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TICKETID ORDER BY TO_CHAR(LDTEXT))  AS Duplicated
        FROM
            MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION INNER JOIN MAXIMO.PLUSCA ON LDKEY = TICKETUID
        WHERE LDOWNERCOL IN ('DESCRIPTION', 'PROBLEMCODE')
            AND (LDOWNERCOL = 'DESCRIPTION' 
                OR LDOWNERCOL = 'PROBLEMCODE'
                OR LDOWNERCOL = 'TYPE1CODE'
                OR LDOWNERCOL = 'TYPE2CODE')
 )   
WHERE   
    Duplicated = 1
```

When I run this, it throws the error from the `TO_CHAR(LDTEXT)`, but if I add in the follow to filter out large text fields it works. How can I compensate this?

```
WHERE LDOWNERCOL IN ('DESCRIPTION', 'PROBLEMCODE')
            AND (DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(LDTEXT) < 2000)
```

Comment: Did you consider hashing the `LDTEXT` column, i.e. with [`STANDARD_HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: DDL statements for your tables (how does the text column store both `CLOB` and `BLOB` types?); DML statements for some sample data; your code that you are running (your current code will not run is syntactically invalid as its missing commas and does not make sense as you are filtering on the same column twice); and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare CLOBs you need to use DBMS_LOB.COMPARE() since TO_CHAR() converts a CLOB to a varchar2. Since Varchar2 is limited in length, you cannot convert a CLOB implicit when length of CLOB exceeds maximum lenght of Varchar2. Please see my example below. First Select works with TO_CHAR() when CLOB got length of 2000 chars or less - otherwise ORA-22835 is raised. Using in second Select DBMS_LOB.COMPARE() works

```
connect scott/tiger

drop table t1;
drop table t2;

create table t1 (col1 number, col2 clob);

insert into t1 values 
(1, 'aaaaaaaaa');
insert into t1 values 
(2, 'bbbbbbbbb');
insert into t1 values 
(3, 'AAAAAAAAAA');

declare
x varchar2(110) ;
c clob;
i integer;
begin
  x := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(c, TRUE); 
  for i in 1..80 loop
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND(c, to_clob(x));
    null;
    end loop;
  update t1 set col2 = c where col1 = 3;  
end;
/

create table t2 as select * from t1;

-- will work for rows 1 + 2  - fails for row 3 since clob length exceeds 2000

select * from t1, t2  where to_char(t1.col2) = to_char(t2.col2);

-- work since DBMS_LOB.COMPARE() is used to compare lobs

select * from t1,t2  where DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(t1.col2,t2.col2) = 0;
```

Output:

```
Connected.
SQL> SQL>
Table dropped.

SQL>
Table dropped.

SQL> SQL>
Table created.

SQL> SQL>   2
1 row created.

SQL>   2
1 row created.

SQL>   2
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SQL>
Table created.

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> ERROR:
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual:
8080, maximum: 4000)



no rows selected

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>
      COL1
----------
COL2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      COL1
----------
COL2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
aaaaaaaaa
         1
aaaaaaaaa


      COL1
----------
COL2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      COL1
----------
COL2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         2
bbbbbbbbb
         2
bbbbbbbbb


      COL1
----------
COL2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      COL1
----------
COL2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         3
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         3
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```